# taxonomy-term--vocabulary.tpl.php still shows tagged content

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, theming

I'm trying to show on my taxonomy term page only what's in *taxonomy-term--myvocabulary.tpl.php*, but :

- If I enable **the taxonomy/term/% view**, what's in my **template is not displayed**
- If I enable **the term panel page**, what's in my **template is not displayed**
- If I disable that view and that panel, what's in my template **is displayed**, but **content tagged with that term is also displayed**.

EDIT: My template outputs several lists of content, uses APIs and webservices, I can't really explain here what it's made of, it's 350 lines of code :) Anyway, I'm sure the content of it is not related to solving that problem.

**Q: What do I have to do to avoid processing and displaying of that tagged content ?**

Comment: If you want the best advice, perhaps you need to describe what you are actually trying to achieve, not how you are trying to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to show on my taxonomy term page only what's in taxonomy-term--myvocabulary.tpl.php

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't answer the question. What's in that file, and what do you hope the output to look like?

Comment: I guess my question must be badly asked. I'm not asking for help on the content of my file, but on the fact that **content tagged with the term is always displaying**, after my file's output. I'm looking for a how-to tell Drupal **not to process and display anything but my file's content on the term page**.

Comment: So, what's in your template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I now think I know what you want, here's what I'd do: use Page Manager to override the default display, then add the rendered Entity display for Taxonomy. That should then pull in your custom template,